# How can i print out input from the user in C#?

Tags: c#

hey i barely started my C# class so i am fairly new with programming. i am having trouble printing out the input from the user. When i ask the user to enter the number of miles ran this week it will show the input but then print out 0. Also when it suppose to print out "This car is owned by" i get a formatexception was unhandled error and stops the program. specifically it says Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. How do i fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework1
{
    class Car
    {
        private string color;
        private int numOfWheels;
        private int startingPoint;
        private int mileage;
        private int currentSpeed;

        public Car()
        {
            color = "";
            NumOfWheels = 4;
            StartingPoint = 100000;
            CurrentSpeed = 0;
            Mileage = 0;
        }

        public Car(string color, int numOfWheels, int startingPoint, int currentSpeed, int mileage)
        {
            Color = color;
            NumOfWheels = numOfWheels;
            StartingPoint = startingPoint;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
            Mileage = mileage;
        }

        public virtual string Color
        {
            get
            {
                return color;
            }
            set
            {
                color = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int NumOfWheels
        {
            get
            {
                return numOfWheels;
            }
            set
            {
                numOfWheels = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int StartingPoint
        {
            get
            {
                return startingPoint;
            }
            set
            {
                startingPoint = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int CurrentSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return currentSpeed;
            }
            set
            {
                currentSpeed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int Mileage
        {
            get
            {
                return mileage;
            }
            set
            {
                mileage = value;
            }
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (" color " + color + " numOfWheels" + numOfWheels + "startingPoint " + startingPoint + "mileage" + mileage + "current speed" + currentSpeed);
        }
    }
}
********************************************************************************
///this is the test case


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework1
{
    class CarTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Car myCar = new Car();


            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
            Console.WriteLine("*                           *");
            Console.WriteLine("*  WELCOME TO CAR MANAGER   *");
            Console.WriteLine("*    By <<my Name>>         *");
            Console.WriteLine("*                           *");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");



            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of wheels of a car");
            int numOfWheels = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(myCar.NumOfWheels);



            Console.WriteLine("Enter the color of the car");
            String color = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(myCar.Color);

            Console.WriteLine("Current mileage will be set to zero");

            Console.WriteLine("The current starting point will be set to 100000");

            Console.Write("The current status of your car \n{0:D} Wheels, \n{1}, \n{2:D} Miles and \nCAR POINT = {3:D}", myCar.NumOfWheels,
            myCar.Color, myCar.Mileage, myCar.StartingPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the owner's name");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the miles the car ran in this week");
            int mileage = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(myCar.Mileage);

            Console.WriteLine("This car is owned by n{1}", name);
            ///this is where the program stops and i get the error message


            Console.WriteLine("===>The current status of your car:");
            Console.WriteLine("Wheels: " + myCar.NumOfWheels);
            Console.WriteLine("Color: " + myCar.Color);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Mileage: " + myCar.Mileage);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Point: " + myCar.StartingPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("************ Thank you for using CAR MANAGER *************");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close console…….");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you last posted this exact program in your previous question only an hour ago, I showed you how to set a property value. There was also someone who commented on the *exact cause* for this problem you're having now...

Answer (score 4):

You have the same error in all your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of wheels of a car");
int numOfWheels = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(myCar.NumOfWheels);
```

You're storing the values in a temporal variable but you're not assigning it to the myCar instance, then myCar.(whatever) will always be null.

Assign it to the class properties and it should work:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the number of wheels of a car");
myCar.NumOfWheels = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(myCar.NumOfWheels);
```